# Node.js issue with async.eachSeries. How to set up callback function to return json file for each element of arrayOfQueryData?

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, asynchronous

This is what I do: I'm using async.eachSeries to multiple call a function that returns array pointsForFormating. And every time I call that function I format array pointsForFormating and put result in array pointsFormated.  I want to return this array pointsFormated as a json file. Because of multiple call of a function this means there is multiple number of json files. I wrote some code for a callback function but it doesn't work correctlly with async.eachSeries. Any suggestions?

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
console.log('Receving request...');

    var callback = function(err, result) {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=nameForJsonFile.json');
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/json'
    });
      console.log('json:', result);
      res.end(result);  
    };  

async.eachSeries(arrayOfQueryData, function(queryData, callback) {
console.log("Query data: " + queryData);    

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'xxxx',
    password : 'xxxx',
    database : 'xxxx',
    port: 3306
}); 

connection.connect();
var json = '';
var data = queryData + '%';
var query = 'SELECT LNG, LAT FROM table WHERE postcode LIKE "' + data;
connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err)
        return callback(err, null);

        if(results.length > 0)
        {               
            var arrayOfPoints = new Array();
            for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            {
                arrayOfPoints[i] = new Array();
                arrayOfPoints[i][0] = results[i].LNG;
                arrayOfPoints[i][1] = results[i].LAT;           
            }


            //do something with points and get result in array named for example, 
            //pointsForFormating

            var pointsFormated = new Array();
            for(var i=0; i<hullPoints.length; i++)
            {
                pointsFormated[i] = {lng: pointsForFormating[i][0], lat:pointsForFormating[i][1]};
            }

            json = JSON.stringify(pointsFormated);


            connection.end();
            console.log('JSON-result:\n', json);

            callback(null, json);
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("No results for: \n" + queryData + "\n");
            connection.end();
            callback(null, json);
        }
    })
  });

 }
 ).listen(9999);

 console.log("Server started @ localhost:9999");
```

Comment: Did you tried ? : res.status(200).json(object);

Comment: eachSeries(arr, iterator, callback) you have not callback

Comment: Yes, missing callback was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I added a response for users.

Answer (score 0):

`eachSeries(arr, iterator, callback)` you have not callback

Comment: Even though this answers the question you should make your answer a bit more readable by including the necessary change in OP's code.